# Configure dds in config file to work with 2 network interfaces

Tags: network-interface, data-distribution-service, rti-dds

How can I configure RTI DDS in the user_QoS_profiles.xml config file to work on a device with 2 NICs(network interface card)?

I want that the publisher(datawriter) sends data with one NIC and the subscriber(datareader) receives data with another NIC.

I have tried to add "dds.transport.UDPv4.builtin.parent.allow_interfaces" and "dds.transport.UDPv4.builtin.parent.deny_interfaces" in the config file, but it seems that I cannot set the default NIC used by datawriter to send data.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer you based on the information in the article [How do I configure DDS to work with multiple network interfaces?](https://community.rti.com/forum-topic/how-do-i-configure-dds-work-multiple-network-interfaces) they mention that:

> You cannot specify which NICs DDS will use to send data. Generally speaking and independently of DDS, there is no way to control which interface IP data is sent at the application level. This is entirely controlled by the OS routing table.

> You can restrict the NICs that DDS can use to receive data by configuring Participant properties in the QoS on the DataReader, but you cannot tell DDS to use one NIC or another to send the DataWriter data.  Rather, the DataWriter will try to send data to all of the addresses that a DataReader announces when subscribing to data using the interfaces that the Operating System selects.